# What extra features does FB 4.5 offer over FB 4?

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-builder

I am considering upgrading my copy of Flash Builder to 4.5, and would like a list of the new features in the new version before I commit. I have heard that the ASUnit tests integrate better than previously, and that there are some nice features like quick fixes, is there anything else?

Finally, based on your experiences using it, are there any shortcomings to look out for / avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mean to provide a definitive answer here, but I can share a couple of things I noticed:

- You can now launch debugging while editing some other file than the default .mxml application file (big convenience gain for me).
- You won't be able to edit your .mxml in "Design Mode" when using SDK < 4.5.
- Seems generally faster.

Overall, it's pretty much the same than FB4, but somewhat better I'd say.